# HTML Email Footer Not Rendering Correctly on Desktop (Gmail)

Tags: html, css, email

I'm an HTML/CSS newbie and am using a free program called Topol.io to create an HTML footer for an email I'm going to send (in EMMA).

On the Topol site, in Preview mode, it looks correct on both desktop and mobile (2 rows of four buttons across on desktop, one stacked column of buttons on mobile).

However, when I send a test email to myself (in Gmail, on desktop), the buttons are stacked instead of in two rows of 4.

Can someone point out what's wrong with my code? I know it's something to do with the screen size code but I'm not just sure exactly what the change is.

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style type="text/css">
    #outlook a {
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .ReadMsgBody {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .ExternalClass {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .ExternalClass * {
      line-height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    
    table,
    td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
      mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    }
    
    img {
      border: 0;
      height: auto;
      line-height: 100%;
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    }
    
    p {
      display: block;
      margin: 13px 0;
    }
  </style>
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
  <style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
      @-ms-viewport {
        width: 320px;
      }
      @viewport {
        width: 320px;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if mso]><xml>  <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>    <o:AllowPNG/>    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>  </o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml><![endif]-->
  <!--[if lte mso 11]><style type="text/css">  .outlook-group-fix {    width:100% !important;  }</style><![endif]-->
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700);
  </style>
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
      .mj-column-per-25 {
        width: 25% !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background: #FFFFFF;">
  <div class="mj-container" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
    <!--[if mso | IE]>      <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center" style="width:600px;">        <tr>          <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">      <![endif]-->
    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background:#7784C3;font-size:0px;width:100%;" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
              <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;" align="center" border="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:26px 0px 26px 0px;">
                      <!--[if mso | IE]>      <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">        <tr>          <td style="vertical-align:top;width:150px;">      <![endif]-->
                      <div class="mj-column-per-25 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;">
                        <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:11px 0px 11px 0px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:25px;" align="center">
                                <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="center" border="0">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="border:none;border-radius:24px;color:#fff;cursor:auto;padding:10px 25px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ff2166"><a href="http://www.bubblesacademy.com/new-parent-baby/" style="text-decoration:none;background:#ff2166;color:#fff;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;line-height:120%;text-transform:none;margin:0px;"
                                          target="_blank">Programs</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:11px 0px 11px 0px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:25px;" align="center">
                                <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="center" border="0">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="border:none;border-radius:24px;color:#fff;cursor:auto;padding:10px 25px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ff2166"><a href="http://www.bubblesacademy.com/contact-us/" style="text-decoration:none;background:#ff2166;color:#fff;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;line-height:120%;text-transform:none;margin:0px;"
                                          target="_blank">Contact</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                      <!--[if mso | IE]>      </td><td style="vertical-align:top;width:150px;">      <![endif]-->
                      <div class="mj-column-per-25 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;">
                        <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:11px 0px 11px 0px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:25px;" align="center">
                                <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="center" border="0">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="border:none;border-radius:24px;color:#fff;cursor:auto;padding:10px 25px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ff2166"><a href="http://www.bubblesacademy.com/class-calendar/" style="text-decoration:none;background:#ff2166;color:#fff;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;line-height:120%;text-transform:none;margin:0px;"
                                          target="_blank">Schedule</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:11px 0px 11px 0px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:25px;" align="center">
                                <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="center" border="0">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="border:none;border-radius:24px;color:#fff;cursor:auto;padding:10px 25px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ff2166"><a href="http://www.bubblesacademy.com/curriculum/" style="text-decoration:none;background:#ff2166;color:#fff;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;line-height:120%;text-transform:none;margin:0px;"
                                          target="_blank">Preschool</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                      <!--[if mso | IE]>      </td><td style="vertical-align:top;width:150px;">      <![endif]-->
                      <div class="mj-column-per-25 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;">
                        <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:11px 0px 11px 0px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:25px;" align="center">
                                <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="center" border="0">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="border:none;border-radius:24px;color:#fff;cursor:auto;padding:10px 25px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ff2166"><a href="http://www.bubblesacademy.com/class-calendar/" style="text-decoration:none;background:#ff2166;color:#fff;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;line-height:120%;text-transform:none;margin:0px;"
                                          target="_blank">Events</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:11px 0px 11px 0px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:25px;" align="center">
                                <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="center" border="0">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="border:none;border-radius:24px;color:#fff;cursor:auto;padding:10px 25px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ff2166"><a href="http://www.bubblesacademy.com/what-we-do/" style="text-decoration:none;background:#ff2166;color:#fff;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;line-height:120%;text-transform:none;margin:0px;"
                                          target="_blank">About Us</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                      <!--[if mso | IE]>      </td><td style="vertical-align:top;width:150px;">      <![endif]-->
                      <div class="mj-column-per-25 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;">
                        <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:11px 0px 11px 0px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:25px;" align="center">
                                <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="center" border="0">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="border:none;border-radius:24px;color:#fff;cursor:auto;padding:10px 25px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ff2166"><a href="http://www.bubblesacademy.com/birthdays/" style="text-decoration:none;background:#ff2166;color:#fff;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;line-height:120%;text-transform:none;margin:0px;"
                                          target="_blank">Parties</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:11px 0px 11px 0px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:25px;" align="center">
                                <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="center" border="0">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="border:none;border-radius:24px;color:#fff;cursor:auto;padding:10px 25px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ff2166"><a href="http://www.bubblesacademy.com/blog/" style="text-decoration:none;background:#ff2166;color:#fff;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:17px;font-weight:normal;line-height:120%;text-transform:none;margin:0px;"
                                          target="_blank">Blog</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                      <!--[if mso | IE]>      </td></tr></table>      <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--[if mso | IE]>      </td></tr></table>      <![endif]-->
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You made four column instead of two. Make two column instead of four.

Comment: I want there to be four columns on desktop, though